# iPhone - Including subviews and possible memory leak?

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller, subview

When writing this common statements :

```
UIViewController* viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myXIB" bundle:nil];
/* do some things with the viewController */
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
```

I'm wondering if there is a possible memory leak here, because :

- viewController is not released by code
- calling [viewController release] after having inserted it in self.view makes the app crash
- viewController is not known by self.view because it is not directly inserted, so releasing self.view should not release viewController

So I see a memory leak here where viewController is never released.

Could you give me your **expert** knowledge about that ?

Note : Instruments does not find any memory leak there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want view as a sub view I think its only better to have the view controller as an instance variable of the class and `release` it in `dealloc`

**UPDATE**

Taken from a previous SO question

> Instrument's leak detection works by
>   conservatively scanning memory,
>   looking for pointers and building a
>   graph of connections between
>   allocations. If it finds any
>   pointer(s) to an object in memory that
>   can be reached from a global variable
>   or stack variable, then that object
>   cannot be considered leaked.
>
> Instruments does not know the layout
>   or context of a pointer. If you were
>   to malloc(1024) and there happened to
>   be a bunch of pointers in that
>   [recycled] chunk of memory, those
>   would count even though you will never
>   treat those pointers as real
>   references again.
>
> So, no, Leaks can never be 100%
>   accurate. As well, there are far more
>   many ways to leak memory than an
>   actual leak.

Comment: Instruments does not find any memory leak there. Do you know why ?

Comment: As I know from WWDC'10 lections Instruments guarantees that all finded leaks are real, but it doesn't guarantee, that it will find all leaks. Most of them, but not all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, memory will leak, you should always release memory allocated by yourself.
When you add `[viewController release]` the viewController is dealloced immediately and then your app crashes, because it's trying to access dealloced memory. To prevent it, you should include your viewController as instance variable of your class.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a leak here as you allocate a new UIViewController but never release it (it is not added to the autorelease pool as you do an allocation). You have to keep a reference on this viewController object and release it later on.

As you said, if you call right after [viewController release], it does crash your application because you have just added its internal view to self.view but the reference counter of the controller to which this view (viewController) belongs has not been incremented.

Comment: Instruments does not find any memory leak there. Do you know why ?

Answer (score 0):

Tableview didselrowatindex method is a common place where such memory leaks occur.

One way to do away with memory leaks is to make sure you only create one instance of the ViewController and then reuse it.

Furthermore this technique doesn't just apply to creating and showing viewcontrollers but anything.  If you are creating anything in code such as uilabels, etc, make sure that you are not creating multiple instances.

/* code */

```
// in the interface create an ivar ... or a property if needed
UIViewController *childViewController;
```

/// then later in your code , tableview didSelectRow, etc

```
// don't create multiple instances of the VC, rather, check to see if we can reuse one
if (! childViewController)
{
   childViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
}

// do some things with the viewController 
childViewController.someProperty = someValue;
[self.view addSubview:childViewController.view];
```